# What class should i choose from android youtube api?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to reproduce a video with an intent and I need that the video activity ends when the video finalize and I need the different resultCodes (if the video ends fine or pushed back button). I tryed different ways to do that:

- With YouTubeIntents --> video works fine and activity ends when the video finalize but resultCode is always RESULT_CANCELED.
- With YouTubeStandalonePlayer --> video works fine and there are different resultCodes but activity doesn't finalize when video ends.

So, What class should i use for these 2 requirements?

PS: It seems that API_KEY is working fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "when the video finalize"? What functionality of Youtube API are you trying to execute? Can you give a clear picture of what your app does?

Comment: - "When the video finalize" means that youtube activity plays the video and playing cursor reseaches the end of the bar.
- As I said y tryed with YouTubeIntents and YouTubeStandalonePlayer.
- I need a first activity with a button who launch the second activity (youtube player). The video should start automatically and at the end of the video i need to automatically come back to the first activity but i need to know if the come back to the first activity was by the end of the video or by the push of back button.
PS: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube API has a `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener` interface that has an `onVideoEnded()` method. You can write your conditions inside the onVideoEnded() to meet your needs.